# Remove unwanted hyphens using "Find & Replace"

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

How do I remove unwanted hyphens from some text I have copied out of a PDF into Word. The criteria is that I would like to remove any hyphen that does not have a space either to its left or right.

Currently, the words look like this because of the way they have been copied: `The qui-ck brown fox- jumps o-ver the lazy dog.` By the end, I only want the hyphen between fox and jumps to survive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this into the Find box: `[! ]-[! ]` (note the spaces after the !) Make sure that "Use Wildcards" is checked.

Explanation:

`[! ]` Any non-space character. The `[` and `]` characters group patterns together while the `!` negates it.

`-` This is the literal character `-`

So `[! ]` `-` `[! ]` is a `-` with non-space characters on either side.

Example character string that matches: `foo-bar`

Example character strings that do not match: `foo- bar` `foo - bar` `foo -bar` `foobar`, etc.

Comment: Can you please explain this?  What does it do, what rules does it use?

Comment: It makes use of the wildcard support in Notepad++. Essentially, it matches any sequence of characters that follow the pattern <Any Non-space character><literal '-'><Any Non-space character>